# How to override a file in root/setup/src/Magento/ in Magento?

Tags: overrides, setup, installer

I'm working on a solution that requires adding a bit of functionality to the magento installation process.  How do I override a file in `root/setup/src/Magento/...`

How would i override  `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can do this in Magento directly. But `composer` may be of some assistance.

```
...
"autoload": {
    ...
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php",
        "setup/src/My/Setup/Model/Installer.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**",
        "setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php"
    ]
}
...
```

The `files` array tells composer to load those files first. The `exclude-from-classmap` array tells composer to not load the file at all. So don't load the core file, copy it somewhere, make your modifications, and load your new file.

Comment: I've done what you stated, issued a composer update, and confirmed my file is being loaded... But breakpoints still fire on the original file.

Comment: try `composer dumpautoload` command to make sure composer flushed its autoloader completely. If this doesn't help, try `composer update --lock` to make sure the changes where updated in the project state.